# Using Maven license plugin in multimodule project

Tags: maven

I am working on a multi-module projects where all modules share a common licence (Apache 2.0). Now I want to add headers to all source files and I want to configure this in the parent's pom.xml (packaging type is pom)

I created a folder `license` in the base dir and added a file `licenses.properties` where I state `apache_2_0=apache_2_0`. Also, I added a subfolder `apache_2_0` where I have two files `header.txt` and `license.txt`. Now I added the following plugin to my parent pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <licenseName>apache_2_0</licenseName>
                <licenseResolver>${project.basedir}/license</licenseResolver>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-file-header</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run this, I do however get an error message:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:license-maven-plugin:1.5:update-file-header
>   (default) on project (myproject): could not obtain the license
>   repository: unknown protocol: c -> [Help 1]

with the following exception:

> java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not defined any protocole (file://, http://, ...) on your `licenseResolver`

replace

```
<licenseResolver>${project.basedir}/license</licenseResolver>
```

with

```
<licenseResolver>file://${project.basedir}/license</licenseResolver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply use ${project.baseUri}